# Django: outputting JSON, not OrderedDict

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a strange problem.

I have an API built with the Django REST framework.

I'm making a call and getting the following JSON back:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "result": {
    "user_type": "ta",
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "mobile_phone": "555-555-5555",
    "id": "0f165a85-2da6-4dcb-97cb-bf04900a942b"
  }
}
```

I've tried to add a logging middleware when I'm trying to get the same output from `response.data` and writing int into a text field in my database.

For the very same request `response.data` is this: (and this gets written into my db, instead of the desired JSON string from above):

```
{'success': True, 'result': OrderedDict([('user_type', 'ta'), ('email', 'myemail@gmail.com'), ('first_name', 'John'), ('last_name', 'Smith'), ('mobile_phone', '555-555-5555'), ('id', UUID('0f165a85-2da6-4dcb-97cb-bf04900a942b'))])}
```

Why is that? How can I get get rid of that `OrderedDict` and get a perfect JSON string from `response.data`?

Please note: `json.dumps` doesn't work. I'm getting `TypeError: Object of type 'UUID' is not JSON serializable`. My entire ID system in the models is based on UUIDs. However, my Django REST framework is capable of serializing it just fine in the above example... how is that done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hitting this problem because you're trying to dump the internal representation using `json.dumps`, which doesn't know how to handle UUID objects.

I can see two options - one, teach `dumps` how to serialize a UUID. This can be done by subclassing [`JSONDecoder`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders), e.g. this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3768975/37481).

However, DRF already knows how to serialize these fields. Poking around in the debugger, it looks like the response text is stashed in `response.rendered_content`. I'd check if that's populated by the time your middleware is run.

Comment: Ha. It is there, as bytes but easily convertible. Thanks. I also found a solution with subclassing JSONDecoder (posted it here). But as you've covered both options, I'll select your answer as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
json.dumps(log_data, indent=2)
```

this can format your dict to the str you want.

eg:

```
    # save log_data in some way
    log_data = {
          "success": True,
          "result": {
            "user_type": "ta",
            "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "mobile_phone": "555-555-5555",
            "id": "0f165a85-2da6-4dcb-97cb-bf04900a942b"
          }
        }
    logger.info(json.dumps(log_data, indent=2))
    print(json.dumps(log_data, indent=2), type(json.dumps(log_data, indent=2)))
```

logger save to django.log like:
[image]

Comment: the problem is that `json.dumps` fails with `TypeError: Object of type 'UUID' is not JSON serializable` when called like that.

Comment: I managed to find a solution. Look at the answer I posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find this posted solution.

https://arthurpemberton.com/2015/04/fixing-uuid-is-not-json-serializable

I added the code to my models and now I do not get `TypeError: Object of type 'UUID' is not JSON serializable` when I serialize my UUID fields. This allowed me to call `json.dumps` on my `response.data` and serialize it to text perfectly.